# cancan validate form values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

Is there a way to authorize form elements with cancan? The code below has a select box for agencies and it only lists agencies which are accessible by current user but someone can edit form and change id of the agency that way he can add brand to another agency. Is there a way to restrict these types of things in cancan, if not how can i check values ?

```
can :read, Agency, :id => user.agencies_as_admin
can :create, Brand
```

form

```
<%= form_for(@brand) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :agency_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :agency_id, Agency.accessible_by(current_ability), :id, :name %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to prevent users from intentionally sending unauthorized data to your application, so you will have to check the authorization in the update and create actions of the controller, before actually creating the brand resource. Something like

```
agency = Agency.find(params[:brand][:agency_id])
authorize! :read, agency
```